JBoss EAP8 ClassNotFoundException com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixSystem
Our application is trying to load the "com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixSystem" during runtime (something different on Windows and Solaris, just saying)
and since the upgrade to EAP8 we are getting a ClassNotFoundException for "UnixSystem" (with jdk11 and 17).
I confirmed via JShell that the JDKs on the machine definitely contains the class :)
Assumption is the we have to enable/active something in a deployment-structure.xml or similar!?

Typical "you probably shouldn't use JDK types" response, but you'd need to add a module dependency on jdk.security.auth.

Thanks! In detail we had to add the following to our deployment-structure.xml
